# Substraction from multiple rows in the right order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help creating a spreadsheet to take money and pay back money to different credit lines.

I have a spreadsheet with 3 credit lines (each with different amounts of money I can borrow). Now I want to make some investments and take money from these different credit lines in a specific order (because of different interest rates).

Therefore I prepared this spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kT5rRZYbkVX_2E-bMRuHVKEynjqgml9y2qqn6uIHp7U/edit?usp=sharing

For sure these investments should payout after a specific period and I want to pay back the money to those credit lines, but in the reversed direction (pay back money to the credit line with the highest interest rates first). And if any money is left after paying back all credit lines it should be added to the bank balance.

After trying the whole day to get this done with some formulas I have no idea left how I can do this, and wanted to ask for your help. Here's some picture to describe it better:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!
Tobias

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser, please include your sample data as part of your question, otherwise your question becomes useless for future users once the link goes dead. It would also be useful to know if yo are working in Excel or Google Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to create helper columns and subtotal columns to keep track.
Furthermore, it also helps to consider the total money in and out as a single amount. The sign of this single amount of money determines if your are loaning more or paying back.

[image]

To determine what amount you should borrow or take from your bank account

```
=MIN(*available in account*, *amount to loan*)
```

and for the rest

```
=MIN(*available in account*, *amount to loan* - sum(*amounts loaned already above*))
```

Now if the *amount to loan* is negative (income to payback) then begin first with the overdraft

```
=MIN(*amount owed to overdraft*,*total income less expenses*)
```

and the rest

```
=MIN(*credit max* - *amount credit available currently*, *total income* - sum(*amounts repaid already below*))
```

You can now put it all together like so:

```
=IF(*expenses* - *income* >= 0, *loan more as first two formula*, *repay as per two latter formula*)
```

Also see the example:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mobus,

awesome! Thanks a lot for your help it worked totally fine!